# Interpreting the RGB or HEX value from a description of the color using NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, 3d-reconstruction

We do have models that predict the basic color from its description, by basic color I mean red, blue, black etc. But I would like to develop a model that can spit out the RGB or HEX colors by a description of it, an example being, "yellow that is glossy and sorta dark" should give the respective value for the same. Another example would be, "Clear green plastic". This is relative to 3d modelling where I input this text and change the material of the object on the screen.

Comment: Look at encoder-decoders more generally (not limited to NMT).

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1492/

Comment: @clef can you be a little specific?

Comment: @user3067860 whats that?

Comment: @Loukik https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1492:_Dress_Color It's a cartoon based on an image of a dress that went viral because no one can agree on what color the dress is. In the cartoon, the two dresses are both the exact same color, just the background and the person change.

Comment: @Loukik Encoders decoders are used in several applications, including (but not limited to) neural machine translation (NMT). For example, Seq2seq approaches are encoder-decoders applied to language (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seq2seq), autoencoders are applied to unsupervised learning of features (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder), etc. You might find things of interest in other approaches with the same enc-dec architecture principle.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you want to translate "yellow that is glossy and sorta dark" by (170,173,11).

A good way to solve this, is by using a neural machine translation model.

Therefore, you can use a encoder/decoder system like many translation models, but with 3 digits as output. To achieve this, you will want to have training data with plenty of text to color translation, but they don't need to be too exhaustive if you cover enough scenarios. The output sequence could be 3 digits 170 173 11. The neural machine translation should adapt itself to the different results automatically, and make good predictions because we have a similar sequence structure as any language.

You have plenty of neural machine translation code examples, here is one among others: https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-neural-machine-translation-system-keras/

Comment: Thanks for that, will use this idea

Comment: You're welcome. Be aware that the best output would be 3 integers digits, but it would require a specific decoder, i.e. some modifications of a language translation's decoder. It is due to the incremental nature of RGB digits: such a translation system should guess the increase or the decrease of R,G and B according to the color description (ex: "quite dark" means a decrease of each RGB values, or "very clear" means an important increase of each RGB values). This system would be better to translate shades than plain text as output.

Comment: yeah I was thinking about the same, I will have to try different ways and firstly gather the training data, do let me know if you have any links or references that might help, thanks once again.